# Custom RouteConfig interfere with HttpPost return View()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a couple of custom routes configured and it seems to be interfering with my controller.  The GET Index action works fine, but if the POST Index action returns the View something goes haywire.  It ends up going to a different route or something.  So I go to my website here http://mywebsitehere/sms and it runs through the GET Index action fine and it renders the form.

When I submit the form, it runs through the POST Action and if the ModelState isn't valid then gets to the `return View(model)` line.  Then I get an error in my `NavigationController` because it's trying to get some RouteData that isn't there.  It shouldn't ever end up in my NavigationController.

My route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Notifications",
    url: "sms/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SMS", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Conference",
    url: "conf/{conferenceCode}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { conferenceCode = "", controller = "Home", action = "Overview" }
);
```

Here's an example of my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.IsHome = true;
    ViewBag.Theme = "a";

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(SendSMSPageViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // DO STUFF HERE

        ModelState.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SMS", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @* My Form stuff here *@
}
```

Comment: try using `return View("Index", model);` and see if that fixes it?  What error is your NavigationController throwing exactly?  And what RouteData is it expecting/looking for?

Comment: The problem is that NavigationController should not be running at all with this view. So the error and RouteData are irrelevant.  I made the change to the return and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug on my part. Someone gave me some advice and I figured out the problem. Some code I didn't post before:

```
ViewBag.IsHome = false;
```

This was in my GET but not my POST and without it runs a partial view which I didn't want to run.